# Can you someone explain 'query_string' vs 'headers' in this situation

Tags: django, websocket, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-channels

Can you someone explain 'query_string' vs 'headers' in this situation. This is from a consumers.py file from a Django project.

```
query_string = parse_qs(scope['query_string'])
query_string = parse_qs(scope['headers'])
```

Also how do I know how I am passing a token when trying to connect a websocket.

Comment: Give us more context. Show us the definition of scope, and the code of `consumers.py`

Answer (score 2):

That is basically the Django channels equivalent of HTTP GET parameters (query_string) vs HTTP headers (headers). They are described here: https://github.com/django/asgiref/blob/master/specs/www.rst